# Regex does not work in IE9

Tags: regex, internet-explorer-9

Any ideas as to why the following doesn't work for any of the IE9 betas? IE8 fine (or IE9 running compatibility mode):

```
if(b.msie){
  b.ver = /MSIE (\d+(.\d+)?)/.exec(ua)[1];
 }else if(b.mozilla){
  b.ver = /Firefox\/(\d+(.\d+)?)/.exec(ua)[1];
 }else if(b.opera){
  b.ver = /Opera\/? ?(\d+(\.\d+)?)/.exec(ua)[1];
 }else if(b.safari){
  b.ver = /Version\/(\d+(\.\d+)+)/.exec(ua)[1];
 }else if(b.chrome){
  b.ver = /Chrome\/(\d+(\.\d+)+)/.exec(ua)[1];
 }
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Error message? Unexpected result? Nothing happens? Computer blows up?

Comment: Does it make coffee instead of tea?

Comment: could it be that IE9 reports its user agent differently from previous versions, and so doesn't match the string? Also, have you considered that browser detection is probably a bad idea anyway? Feature dection is usually better than browser detection, precicely because of issues like this - browser detection tends to break when new versions are released (as demonstrated). Plus user agent strings can be overridden or even blocked entirely, meaning that your browser detection script can be fooled by the user.

Answer (score 0):

don't you want `String.match()`? e.g. `b.ver = ua.match(/MSIE (\d+(\.\d+)?)/)[1];`
you also need to escape the `.` outside a character class.